# Как можно получить параметр переданный в URL загружаемого на странице сценария JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Допустим есть страница index.html на которой загружается сценарий JavaScript к примеру кодом:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js?param=1"></script>
```

Как в этом случаи им загружаемого скрипта получить значение параметра param который был передан в URL загружаемого скрипта.

P.S. Про способ получить на странице все html элементы script затем проверить их URL на предмет нужного адреса скрипта, а затем при совпадении получить параметр - я знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот несколько способов передачи параметров в скрипт, но они не будут работать если скрипт загружается как модуль (`type="module"`), т.к. используют свойство [document.currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript):

- используем *queryString* `<script src="customizable.js?q=123" /></script>`:

```js
const u = new URL(document.currentScript.src)
const qs = new URLSearchParams(u.search)
console.log(qs.get("q"))
```

- используем "левый" атрибут `<script src="customizable.js" q="123" /></script>` (не рекомендуется из-за возможных конфликтов со стандартными атрибутами):

```js
console.log(document.currentScript.getAttribute("q"))
```

- используем [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) атрибут `<script src="customizable.js data-q="123"/></script>` (предпочтительный способ):

```js
console.log(document.currentScript.dataset.q)
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Всё доходчиво и по делу(правда ещё не успел проверить).